# Invalid use of Group by in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have following query when I run it over mysql editor it gives error of "invalid use of group by" while using it in jasper reports, it doesn't generate any error? what's wrong with the query?

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.TAXID, 
CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER, 
CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORY,
PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, 
PRODUCTS.NAME AS PRODUCT, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNIT, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) AS TOTAL, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) / SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS MEANPRICE,
PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY AS BUYPRICE,
((SUM(SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE) / SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS)) - PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY) * TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS PROFITLOSS
FROM TICKETS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID, TICKETLINES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID
WHERE RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID AND 
TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET AND 
CATEGORIES.ID = PRODUCTS.CATEGORY
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID, CATEGORIES.ID, PRODUCTS.ID
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS.NAME, 
CATEGORIES.NAME, 
PRODUCTS.NAME
```

Comment: You're adding conditions on a table called `RECEIPTS`, but it's not joined in anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be because you are doing a sum within a sum in the profitloss derivation; there's also a condition in the `where` clause that replicates a `join` condition, and another to an alias `receipt` not mentioned elsewhere - instead, try:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.TAXID, 
       CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER, 
       CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORY,
       PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, 
       PRODUCTS.NAME AS PRODUCT, 
       SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNIT, 
       SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) AS TOTAL, 
       SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) / SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS MEANPRICE,
       PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY AS BUYPRICE,
       SUM( (TICKETLINES.PRICE - PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY) * TICKETLINES.UNITS ) AS PROFITLOSS
FROM TICKETS 
JOIN TICKETLINES ON TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID, CATEGORIES.ID, PRODUCTS.ID
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS.NAME, CATEGORIES.NAME, PRODUCTS.NAME
```

Comment: Wow, that surprisingly run but I had to add RECEIPT.ID after CATEGORIES.ID in LEFT OUTER JOIN, although I don't know the reason ...

Answer (score 0):

You should have all group fields inside the SELECT group:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.ID, CATEGORIES.ID, PRODUCTS.ID,CUSTOMERS.TAXID, 
CUSTOMERS.NAME AS CUSTOMER, 
CATEGORIES.NAME AS CATEGORY,
PRODUCTS.REFERENCE, 
PRODUCTS.NAME AS PRODUCT, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS UNIT, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) AS TOTAL, 
SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS * TICKETLINES.PRICE) / SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS MEANPRICE,
PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY AS BUYPRICE,
((SUM(SUM(TICKETLINES.PRICE) / SUM(TICKETLINES.UNITS)) - PRODUCTS.PRICEBUY) * TICKETLINES.UNITS) AS PROFITLOSS
FROM TICKETS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID, TICKETLINES 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCTS ON TICKETLINES.PRODUCT = PRODUCTS.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CATEGORIES ON PRODUCTS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID
WHERE RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID AND 
TICKETS.ID = TICKETLINES.TICKET AND 
CATEGORIES.ID = PRODUCTS.CATEGORY
GROUP BY CUSTOMERS.ID, CATEGORIES.ID, PRODUCTS.ID
ORDER BY CUSTOMERS.NAME, 
CATEGORIES.NAME, 
PRODUCTS.NAME
```